# Puppeteer not lauching script on other website return chrome error

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, puppeteer

My goal is to create a puppeteer script that should go to website named in WEBSITE_TO_GO.

The Puppeteer should stay on it for 5 seconds for the hidden form to be sent to the link named 127.0.0.1:25556. Manually there is no problem but with Puppeteer, the form is never launched. The WEBSITE_TO_GO value is having a good value. I have try to search the same case on stackoverflow, but I don't find anything from this range.

Here is my html code from the WEBSITE_TO_GO:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hidden Form Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // Function to send data to the server
        function sendData() {
            var data = {
                username: "Saruman",
                password: "asdasdasd"
            };

            // Create a hidden form dynamically
            var form = document.createElement('form');
            form.action = 'http://localhost:25556/user';
            form.method = 'POST';

            // Append each key-value pair as hidden input fields to the form
            for (var key in data) {
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'hidden';
                input.name = key;
                input.value = data[key];
                form.appendChild(input);
            }
            //Append the form to the body and submit it
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
        //Delay the function call by 5 seconds
        var wait = setTimeout(sendData, 5000);

    </script>

    <img src='https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/isolated-gold-wedding-rings-realistic-260nw-2298601103.jpg' alt="Ring">
    <br>
    <br>

    <form action="https://www.weddingwire.com/wedding-photos/engagement-rings" target="_blank" name="more">
        <button type="submit">Plus de photos de bagues</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Here is my try for the puppeteer script:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const WEBSITE_TO_GO = process.env.WEBSITE_TO_GO;

const createAccount = async () => {
    console.log("start");

    // User_data is a file in which the browser will store persisting info such as cookies and local storage
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        userDataDir: "./admin_data",
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });

    console.log("loading page");

    // Using the same browser object, but another page
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log(WEBSITE_TO_GO);
    await page.goto(WEBSITE_TO_GO, { waitUntil: "load", timeout: 5000 });
    console.log("Has found the page to go to");

    // Your existing code to wait for the image and timeout
    await page.waitForSelector('img', { visible: true });
    console.log("asdasdasd");
    await page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 5000 }); // Adjust the timeout value based on your needs
    console.log("123123123");

    const currentURLAfterSubmission = await page.url();
    console.log("Current URL after form submission:", currentURLAfterSubmission);

    // Uncomment the line below if you want to keep the browser open for inspection
    // await browser.close();
};
createAccount();
```

Comment: @PeterSmith it is a frontEnd application on my vm local on port 127.0.0.1:25556.